# Need a Custom Modified By Column to Track Who Chnaged Another Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint list with a column called Manager Review. I would like to create two columns; one called “Manager Review By” and one Called “Manager Review On”. I would like the Manager Review By column to contain the user name of the user that changes the value (picks a Review choice) from the Manager Review dropdown and the Manager Review On would contain the date the selection was made. I was thinking of trying to use the intrinsic function [Me] in a calculated column, but SharePoint doesn’t allow it. I have a basic understanding of javascript so if that is the route I need to go I think I could work that out with a little help. Thanks in advance! Kevin

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways to implement this (or rather, I should say, a couple ways *I* would implement this), depending on if it is possible for "Manager Review" to be changed multiple times, and if you want to have "Manager Review By" and "Manager Review On" to be updated to reflect the most recent changes to "Manager Review" (or not).

If "Manager Review" can be changed multiple times, and you want to update the other two fields to reflect the most recent changes:

- Create a "Manager Review Previous" column.   It should be a choice column with *identical* choices to the "Manager Review" column.  Make both the "Manager Review" and the "Manager Review Previous" default to the same value when a new item is created, and make the "Manager Review Previous" column *hidden*.
- Make a workflow that runs when an item is updated.
- In the workflow, check the value of "Manager Review" vs. "Manager Review Previous".  If they are different, you know someone changed "Manager Review".
- If it changed:

  - Set your "Manager Review By" to be Current Item: Modified By.
  - Set your "Manager Review On" to be Current Item: Modified.
  - Set "Manager Review Previous" to be Current Item: Manager Review

If you only want to set the values of "Manager Review By" and "Manager Review On" *once*, the first time the "Manager Review" column is changed:

- Make sure that for the "Manager Review" column, you have a choice that represents the fact that the Manager Review has not happened yet. (For example: "Pending".)  It can be whatever phrase makes sense for your situation, but whatever it is, make sure that the "Manager Review" *defaults* to that value when a new item is created.
- Make a "Manager Review Complete" column.  It should be a Yes/No column, make it default to "No", and make it *hidden*.
- Make a workflow that runs when an item is updated.
- In the workflow, check the "Manager Review Complete" value.  If it is "No":

  - Check the value of the "Manager Review" column.  If it is *not* what you know to be the default value representing the review not happening yet (i.e. "Pending"), then you know that the value changed and (because the "Manager Review Complete" column is "No") you haven't recorded the "Review By" person and "Review On" time yet, so:

    - Set the "Manager Review By" to be Current Item: Modified By.
    - Set the "Manager Review On" to be Current Item: Modified,
    - Set "Manager Review Complete" to be **Yes**.

Note that the second example won't actually prevent anyone from going back in and editing the item again and changing the "Manager Review" value to something else, but it will prevent that subsequent change from updating the "Manager Review By" and "Manager Review On", because the "Manager Review Complete" flag field will have already been set to "Yes" the first time, so it will skip the steps in the workflow where it sets those values.

Comment: Brilliant! I am out of the office today, but will give this a try tomorrow morning. Didn't even occur to me to set this up as a workflow; I don't do a ton of work in SP. The first scenario ("Manager Review" can be changed multiple times) could happen - although rarely - so I will set it up as you described for that. Thank you, sir!